# Angular issue for image with Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular Ng-repeat to repeat objects from the scope (each object has 4 properties: entry, title, image, link). Everything seems to be there when I check the html in Chrome developer tools except the image doesn't show up on the page. I'm also using fancybox and themepunch. If I don't use Angular to repeat and manually write the html in my code it works fine. I think the problem might be with data-src and angular not liking this but couldn't find anything to prove my theory. Also might it be the class added mega-entry-innerwrap that loads with the page...I dunno I checked a lot of things (tried replacing data-src with ng-src but didn't work).

Here is the html code....

```
<div class="containerMegafolio">
<div ng-controller="update">
<div ng-repeat="new in news" class="megafolio-container"><img id="entry-{{new.entry}}" data-src="{{new.image}}" data-width="504" data-height="400" class="mega-entry"/>
  <div class="mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-bottom mega-portrait-bottom mega-pink mega-transparent">
    <div class="mega-title">{{new.title}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mega-hover notitle alone">
    <div class="mega-hovertitle">Cliquez ici</div><a href="{{new.link}}">
      <div class="mega-hoverlink"></div></a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the JS script...(I included just one object for shortening this post)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.controller('update', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.news = [
    {
    entry: '1',
    title: 'Title blah blah blah', 
    image: 'images/entry7.jpg', 
    link: "https://www.facebook.com/......"}

];

}]);
```

The URL below should show http://example.com/images/entry7.jpg and not the gibberish below.

```
<div class="mega-entry-innerwrap" style="background: url(http://example.com/%7B%7Bnew.image%7D%7D) 50% 49% / cover no-repeat;"></div>
```

EDIT: Yes it is the below code that doesn't work well with Angular. So now working on a solution. Trying to pre-load images with a promise before running the NG-Repeat see if this works...in the meantime you can check the project on github if you want to try your hand at it. https://github.com/mannyhenri/testload

```
function prepairNewEntries(container,opt,newentry) {

    container.find('>.mega-entry-added').each(function(i) {
            var ent=$(this);
            if (!ent.hasClass('tp-layout')) {

                    ent.removeClass('tp-layout-first-item').removeClass('tp-layout-last-item').removeClass('very-last-item');
                    ent.addClass("tp-notordered");
                    if (newentry) ent.addClass("notplayedyet");
                    ent.wrapInner('<div class="mega-entry-innerwrap"></div>');
                    //ent.find('.mega-socialbar').appendTo(ent)
                    var iw = ent.find('.mega-entry-innerwrap')
                    /*if (opt.ie) {
                        iw.append('<img class="ieimg" src='+ent.data("src")+'>');
                    } else {*/
                        iw.css({'background':'url('+ent.data("src")+')','backgroundPosition':'50% 49%', 'backgroundSize':'cover', 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
                    //}
```

EDIT 2: The closest I got to not undefined in the mega-entry-innerwrap URL is by keeping data-src={{new.image}} in the div and not doing anything to the themepunch code. It does this below...

background: url(http://www.example.com:8080/%7B%7Bnew.image%7D%7D) so instead of undefined is litterally puts my {{new.image}} as my path...maybe write a bit of code to convert into the actual path?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing a background of a `div` instead of `ng-src` on an `img` element?

Comment: Yes, you need to use ng-src. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Yes already tried the Ng-src on the div and also tried changing to img and tried both ng-src and data-src without much success. Is anyone familiar enough with the plugins themepunch and fancybox to know how it reacts to ng-source? Any other ideas?

Comment: Look at my above edited question and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `ng-src` instead of `data-src`, so:

```
<div ng-repeat="new in news" class="megafolio-container">
 <img id="entry-{{new.entry}}" ng-src="{{new.image}}" data-width="504" data-height="400" class="mega-entry"/>
```

EDIT: Seems to be working with above changes in http://jsfiddle.net/5c1v814c/

EDIT: To remove conflict with plugin, you'll need to transition this functionality elsewhere:

```
var iw = ent.find('.mega-entry-innerwrap')
                    /*if (opt.ie) {
                        iw.append('<img class="ieimg" src='+ent.data("src")+'>');
                    } else {*/
                        iw.css({'background':'url('+ent.data("src")+')','backgroundPosition':'50% 49%', 'backgroundSize':'cover', 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
```

At the very least: remove the css setter attr `({'background':'url('+ent.data("src")+')` and see if that causes the conflict.

Comment: Tried it already. Didn't work. I think the problem might be how the two plugins add a new class when loading the page but instead of loading the image path it literally loads the {{new.image}} characters as the background of the image. Any other ideas?

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/5c1v814c/; What other dependencies are you working with? Can you post your bower manifest?

Comment: (Changed the image url to an external placeholder so as not to deal with relative references)

Comment: Marketthomas the animation of the box and its text showing inside the box are using fancybox.js and themepunch.megafolio to load the picture as background with animation, title and link in a div inside the image. My only problem and what breaks the whole thing is the image doesn't get to the resulting code (there seems ng-source doesn't work with those and data-src obviously is a no no with angular.

Comment: dependences: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.megafoliopro.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script> I'm digging in these dependencies code to see if I can change that but they're all minified (just to make matters worst)

Comment: Look at my above edited question and let me know what you think!

Comment: @EmmanuelHenri thanks for the edit! Are any of these dependencies publicly available? (via bower or npm or something). If not I'll still look through it, just curious since that would make it easier to emulate and debug. Have you tried removing those files and seeing if that works?

Comment: You can take a look at the github load I just did for the files in question. I'm pretty the issue is in that line of code I added earlier. I'm playing with it as we speak and feel free to take a look at it. https://github.com/mannyhenri/testload

Comment: I will write my comments in the issue section of the repo. thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm also considering pre-loading my images with promises before the NG-repeat starts like here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm